# Cannot authenticate proxy for Cypress

Tags: proxy, cypress

I am trying to use Cypress on my company PC via VPN however when I start to make my test run via Cypress App, I get an error message that says "Error: Error establishing proxy connection. Response from server was: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required". I can access the url via a normal chrome browser without any problem.

- I tried to modified my http_proxy environment variable for my user in Windows, didn't work
- I tried to add the line proxy: "http://MyUsername:MyPassword@ProxyUrl:PortNumber" to cypress.config.js file, but didn't work.
- Inside my .npmrc file I added proxy and https-procy variables, didn't help

What do you suggest me to do?